# Is there a way to create mechanical relations between models in P5.js?

Tags: angular, processing, p5.js, .obj, solidworks

I would like to use P5.js to render 3D models into my website and I would like to have moving parts that can be adjusted.  I grabbed the following picture off the internet to serve as an example
[image]

Looking at this tool there are 5 core parts that make up the entire thing.  In SolidWorks I could export the individual parts as .obj files or the entire assembly as one .obj file.  In regards to being able to extend and contract this model, I haven't been able to find anything that highlights on doing something like this in P5.js or if there's a way to provide some type of constraints so it'll properly logic out how it's suppose to move without having to nano-animate a whole bunch of things to make it move the way you'd naturally expect it to.  I don't know if I'll be able to do something like that from an assembly model or if I would need to import each part into P5 then iterate and assemble the tool, I really don't know where to begin with doing this.  Does anybody have experience handling something this involved?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to split the problem into smaller simpler chunks.
For example:

1. load part meshes
2. assemble parts
3. simulate parts

For part1, with p5 you should be able use [`loadModel()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadModel) to load each .obj file

In terms of assembling parts you should be able to use [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push)/[`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) to isolate coordinate spaces and group parts.

The trickier part will be the simulation, where you can be simple and limited or complex.

The simplest I can think of is a set of keyframes: key angles for parts that [interpolate](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerp) between.

A more complex option might be to simulate the system using a spring system with stiff springs (constrained rest length). The laser cut pieces looks like extruded 2D shapes that are locked to a 2D plane in terms of moving parts.

If you want to a full 3D rigid body simulation you might want to try a phyics engine like [ammo.js](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/)

This part sounds confusing:

> I would like to have moving parts that can be adjusted.

If the parts can be adjusted, then loading .obj files might not be the way forward unless you have a model for each adjustable version (which will be a **lot** of files to load)
You may need to look into making these shapes parametric:

- defining changing parameters (e.g. radius, length and thickness of a section, number of sections, etc.)
- calculating 3D shape vertices based on parameters (for the examples above could be 2D shape with z offsets as extrusions)
- putting the vertices together into meshes using [`beginShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape)/[`endShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/endShape)